# Why is "a eu" the right tense, not "avait"?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé

I want to find out why "a eu" is the right tense, not "avait".

> Il a toujours eu un sens aigu des limites du savoir humain.

---

> Il avait toujours un sens aigu des limites du savoir humain.

Comment: Both are right. It depends on what you want to say. Maybe you should clarify the context.

Answer (score 1):

"*avait*" is *imparfait*, and implies that the action is **over**, by two means:

- the action is over (narration is in present tense)
- the narration is in past tense, and the action is ongoing in the time you're describing, but over now.

Here I assume it's present tense. If you say:

> Il avait toujours un sens aigu des limites du savoir humain.

it means that the action is over, so now, the "acute sense" is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to use the ***passé composé*** or the ***imparfait***

> **Verbe avoir - Passé composé**
>   j'ai eu
>   tu as eu
>   il a eu
>   nous avons eu
>   vous avez eu
>   ils ont eu

For further details I would suggest you to read [this](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/avoir.php) link.

Comment: Of course but that doesn't answer the question. Why would you use the _passé composé_ and not the _imparfait_ here?

Comment: As Stéphane Gimenez said we need more context in order to make this choice, so I have planned to update my reply once we know the context